# SELECT query for TableA and TableB IF TableB.col value (0 OR 1) I create new columns for 0 and 1

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have a Table **pictures**

```
create table pictures (
  picture_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mall_id float NOT NULL,
  shop_id float NOT NULL,
  picture_islogo int(11) NOT NULL ,
  picture_path varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (picture_id)
) ;
```

Sample Data for pictures

```
INSERT INTO pictures VALUES
(1, -1, 1, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(2, -1, 2, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(3, -1, 3, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(4, -1, 4, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(5, -1, 5, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(6, -1, 6, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(7, -1, 7, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(8, -1, 8, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(9, -1, 9, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(10, -1, 10, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(11, -1, 11, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(12, -1, 12, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(13, -1, 13, 1, 'photo.jpg'),
(14, -1, 13, 0, 'photo.jpg');
```

and other table **malls**

```
 create table malls (
  mall_id float NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id float NOT NULL,
  mall_displaysname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  mall_description text NOT NULL,
  mall_contact varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  mall_logo_picture_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  mall_background_picture_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (mall_id)
);
```

Sample Data for malls

```
    INSERT INTO malls VALUES
    (1, 2, 'mall', 'description', '+60 12 3456789', 14, 36),
    (2, 5, 'mall 2', 'description', '+60 12 3456789', 15, 37),
    (3, 6, 'mall 3', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 16, 38),
    (4, 13, 'Multimedia University', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 17, 39),
    (5, 18, 'Setia Walk', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 18, 40),
    (6, 20, 'Ampang Point', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 19, 41),
    (7, 21, 'Alamanda Plaza', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 20, 42),
    (8, 22, 'Subang Parade', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 21, 43),
    (9, 26, 'مجمع العرب - جدة', 'description ', '+60 12 3456789', 22, 44);
```

Where **`mall_background_picture_id`** and **`mall_background_picture_id`** reference to **`pictures`.`picture_id`** and Depend on the value of **`pictures`.`picture_islogo`** (0: Logo,  1:background or others)

i want a query to that returns the `pictures`.`picture_path` depends on the value of **`pictures`.`picture_islogo`** (0: Logo,  1:background or others)

the data that I need to get
mall_id ,  mall_displaysname, mall_logo, mall_background , mall_description, and mall_contact

Where **`mall_logo`** is the **`photo_path`** of the condition
**`pictures`.`picture_islogo`** = 1

and same thing with `**mall_background**` but 
**`picture_islogo`** = 0 
AND 
**`mall_logo_picture_id`** = **`picture_id`**

Comment: Is it possible for `mall_background_picture_id` and or `mall_logo_picture_id` to be null?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and expected result ?

Comment: I have added a sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the extra condition into the join condition:

```
select * -- you can chose what columns you want
from malls m
left join pictures pl on m.mall_logo_picture_id = pl.picture_id
    and pl.picture_isLogo = 1
left join pictures pb on m.mall_background_picture_id = pb.picture_id
    and pb.picture_isLogo = 0
```

To have left joins, the extra conditions must be in the join condition, which is evaluated as the join is being made.

If you put them in the where clause, which is evaluated after the join is made, you force the outer join to be an inner join, because the join must be successful fur the extra condition to be true.

Comment: thank you it works but now I have the columns on pictures table duplicated twice (one for islogo = 0 and the other for picture_islogo = 1) so now I have the column picture_path twice one for logo and the other for background

I don't need anything from pictures table except picture_path (and rename it logo and background)
   Thank you again

Comment: Found it in SELECT I shoud specify that pl.picture_path AS logo, pb.picture_path AS background.  Thank you very much